# Routing and remote access on Windows Server 2012 locks out RDP and ping

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, remote-access

I have a server with 2 network cards, one unplugged and not in use and the other on a public IP address.

Using remote desktop, I setup Routing and Remote Access (VPN access with NAT), assigned the VPN a private IP range (192.168.1.100 - 199) and routed it through the network card that's connected with the public IP.

I then tested the VPN connection and it worked great, NAT etc. was perfect.

**PROBLEM**
**When I disconnected the remote desktop session I could no longer connect via remote desktop again. I couldn't even ping the machine anymore! I could however still connect to the VPN**

Disabling routing and remote access service fixes the problem but disables my VPN.

Anyone know why that might be?

Comment: Not sure to understand...is there a reason why you use VPN to connect to a server that has a public ip ?

Comment: Im using the VPN to connect to it and share its public IP address for browsing/downloading (its IP has different bandwidth shaping rules to mine)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but I'm pretty sure it's because you turned on the packet filtering feature which is enabled by default in the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I'm leaving here a link to a blog post where I found the solution just in case it can help someone coming later

https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/install-vpn-rras-remote-routing-access/

The important bits are :

- In Routing and Remote Access, expand the server → IPV4 → NAT
- Right click on external network interface (whatever name that interface has), go to properties → Services and ports
- Click on Add, enter the description for this service, enter the RDP port and IP address of the VPS and click on Ok